# awk and cut on a very large file

Tags: awk, textfiles, cut

I have to extract a column of data from a very large file >100GB.

I know how to use the `awk` and `cut` commands do it, but would like to know if one is more efficient (from a speed perspective) for such a task.

Comment: Grep should be the fastest way to search a string in a file: `grep -o "\w*pattern\w*" /path/to/file`. You might want to read also about `parallel` for using multiple `grep`'s on chunks of that file.

Comment: If `cut` can be used, it should be faster, since it is a lot simpler, and thus less capable.